# Getting the max row character length in a query using Perl DBI Mysql

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

Using: Perl v5.10.1, MySQL 5.5.15, DBI.

I need to deliver end users output from a database via email.  They do not want this as an attachment, but in the body.

I'd like to deliver the data in an ascii table and am having issues determining if DBI has built in functions to do this (output similar to querying MySQL from the command line).

Or If I can determine the longest row character length I can use that to build the table.  I have a way to get the max item length in an array, but I can't wrap my head around doing it with the query results.

```
my $spacer_length = (reverse sort { $a <=> $b } map { length($_) } @array)[0];
```

Comment: What do the "query results" look like?

Comment: @ikegami The queries are variable, but basically I'm returning around 6 columns worth of info with multiple rows of data.  The longest field would be varchar(255) although they're mostly under 50 characters I'd say.  I can't really post the query and results here because there is too much sensitive info (and it would be very hard to cover it up).

Comment: We don't need to know the exact data. We need to know the structure of the data.

Comment: `reverse` a sort? Really? That'd be `sort { $b <=> $a }` instead.

Comment: Can you simply avoid the problem and [use Text::Table](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-Table/)?

Comment: @pilcrow That would be my other option.  Trying to avoid modules, but if there isn't another way I can probably work with it.

Comment: @TLP - it works.  I've tried it (not sure if it's the best way, but I found that solution elsewhere - can't remember where unfortunately.

Comment: For example, "I have an array of rows, where each row is a hash. Find the width of the value of the field 'string' for the row that has the largest width for the value of the field 'string'." Right now, you provided no data whatsoever about your input structure, yet you're specifically asking us how to work with your input structure.

Comment: Why don't you show the "query results" so we have a chance to give you an answer. As I understand it, you have some code to read the db using DBI, so show that part.

Comment: Thank you for the comments so far.  I'll see if I can obfuscate my data and update my question later. It's tough when you're working with field names and results that are a bit sensitive but I understand the need for it.

Comment: We don't need to see your data, just your data structures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming a generic DBI loop, you could do something like this:

```
use List::Util qw(max);

...
my @output;
my $max;
while (my @foo = $dbi->fetchrow_array) {
    $max = max($max // (), map length, @foo);
    push @output, \@foo;           # save data for email attachment
}
```

Using the "defined-or" operator `//` to avoid an `undef` warning and possible contamination in case of negative values.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking for, but if you're looking for the "max row character length" for a given column of a query result, you can do that with SQL:

```
SELECT MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(col1)) FROM t1
```

or if you want all of the rows sorted by the length of the values of col1:

```
SELECT col1,col2 from t1 ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(col1) DESC
```

you can execute these queries using DBI like this:

```
# $mysql is your DBI connection info
my $query = $mysql->prepare("SELECT col1,col2 from t1 ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(col1) DESC");
$query->execute();
```

and then iterate through the result rows:

```
while ( my @result = $query->fetchrow_array ) {

    my ($col1,$col2) = @result;
    # do stuff with the values

}
```

and you can print the values as you wish, including like the output from the command line mysql client.